# bluetooth handler Data missing while communicating string sentance. android studio

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth, android-handler, data-transfer

I was trying to transfer sensor data to string sentence to sentence
Arduino send a sentence which is to 'btSerial.read()'
And An app received the sentence with Bluetooth handler.

when I send "<123,456>" the app received sometimes <23,456>" or "<123,456>"
when I send "<10,10>" the app received sometimes "<0,10>>>"...
I don't understand why it happens. Could someone tell me? why?

## Arduino Code

```
include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial btSerial(5,6); //RX, TX

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
btSerial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
if(Serial.available()) {
btSerial.write(Serial.read());        
}

if(btSerial.available()) {
Serial.write(btSerial.read());
}
}
```

And send "<123,456>"  with Serial monitor

### Android Studio - Received data (Handler part)

```
public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
   if (msg.what == handlerState) {
    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
    recDataString.append(readMessage);

    int endOflineIndex = recDataString.indexOf(">");

      if (endOflineIndex > 0) {
        if (flag == 1) {  //Wait until flag=1,after this flag=0.
            Log.d(Tag, String.valueOf(recDataString));
            textview.setText("received data : " + readMessage); 
            }
            recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());
            flag = 0;
            }
         }

        }
      }
      ...
```

### Android Studio - send sensor data part

```
@Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    x = ((int) event.values[0] + 10) * 13;
    y = ((int) event.values[1] + 10) * 13 / 3;

    if (connect) {
        if ( flag ==0) {
            xx = Integer.toString(x);
            yy = Integer.toString(y);
                connectedThread.send("<" + xx + "," + yy + ">");
                flag = 1;
        }
     else {
    }}
```

### Android Studio - Bluetooth Thread part

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

       ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
          InputStream tmpIn = null;
          OutputStream tmpOut = null;
          try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()
        // keep listening to the InputStream untill an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the Inputstream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                final String readingMessage = new String(buffer, "US-ASCII");
                 mHandler.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1,readingMessage).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue while receiving data from an STM micro controller. For me, if I slow the data from the mcu down and shorten the length of data received its not as bad.
The best thing to do is to put and end of message delimiter in your arduino code then check for the delimiter in android. Something like "\n".